# Use multiple domains on same webserver to different folder

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, web

I am trying to use multiple domains on the same webserver but get a different website depending on the domain which was entered. I think this is possible using HTACCESS but I couldn't find anything useful on google.

Here is an example:

www.a.com -> index.php

www.b.com -> /b/index.php

But if someone wants to view B the URL should still be www.b.com with no trace of www.a.com.

Comment: You should check your domain registrar and domain settings. I am pretty sure it can be done from there.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/577306/redirect-multiple-domains-to-subfolders-and-hide-the-subfolder-from-url